# Is there also a shortcut to prevent result from being nil or empty in Swift?

Tags: swift

I can use the following expression to prevent a variable from being nil:

```
let result: String = someTextField.text ?? ""
```

**Is there also a shortcut to prevent `result` from being nil or empty in Swift?**

Comment: Given your sample, `result` will never be `nil`, but it can be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
let result: String = 
         someTextField.text?.isEmpty() != false ? "is null or empty" :  someTextField.text!
```

Comment: `!= false` is totally redundant. You should take it out.

Comment: You mean without ``!= false`` it is the same?

Comment: Yes. It's already a boolean `!= false` is the same as `== true` which is the same as not bothering with the comparison at all

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check it using the `.isEmpty` method or else use a default value

```
let result = (someTextField.text ?? "").isEmpty ? "default" : string
```

Answer (score 0):

`??` is called **Nil Coalescing Operator**

> The nil coalescing operator (`a ?? b`) unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if a is nil. The expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must match the type that is stored inside a.

According to you question, `??` just is the shortcut of preventing `result` from being `nil`.

And there is no shortcut to preventing `result` from being both `nil` and empty. As empty is type `string`, it's different from `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with `??` and `?` but if you want you can define your own short cut.

```
// So we can apply to any type by extending the type to conform to the protocol
protocol CanBeEmpty
{
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
}

extension String: CanBeEmpty
{
    // String doesn't need the var cos it already has it
}

extension Optional where Wrapped: CanBeEmpty
{
    func unwrappedOrDefault(def: Wrapped) -> Wrapped
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .None:
            return def
        case .Some(let wrapped):
            return wrapped.isEmpty ? def : wrapped
        }
    }
}

let foo: String? = "foo"
let fooUnwrapped = foo.unwrappedOrDefault("default") // "foo"
let bar : String? = ""                        
let barUnwrapped = bar.unwrappedOrDefault("default") // "default"
let baz: String? = nil
let bazUnwrapped = baz.unwrappedOrDefault("default") // "default"
```

If you think that is too much typing, create an operator

```
infix operator ??? {}

func ???<T: CanBeEmpty> (a: Optional<T>, b: T) -> T
{
    return a.unwrappedOrDefault(b)
}

foo ??? "default" // "foo"
bar ??? "default" // "default"
baz ??? "default" // "default"
```